# Effective bounds on Euler's totient

Tags: nt.number-theory, effective-results, computational-number-theory

Quick question: It's known that
$$\limsup\frac{n}{\varphi(n)\log\log n}=e^\gamma$$
but are there known C and N such that
$$\varphi(n)>\frac{Cn}{e^\gamma\log\log n}$$
for all $n>N$?

Failing that, what are good effective bounds on $\varphi$?  The square root bound isn't good enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Look at 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Inequalities:

$$\varphi(n)>\frac{n}{e^\gamma\log\log n + \frac{3}{\log\log n}}$$
for $n>2$.